# rename templates folders with a gruntjs custom init task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a custom *init task* for a personal template in [Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt).

This is the js which generate my new project after a `grunt init:mytemplate`

```
exports.description = 'Try Grunt';
exports.warnOn = '*';

exports.template = function(grunt, init, done) {
  grunt.helper('prompt', {type: 'skin'}, [
    grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'name', 'trygrunt'),
    grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'title', 'Im Trying GruntJS'),
    grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'author_name', 'Myself')
  ],
  function(err, props) {
    var files = init.filesToCopy(props);
    init.copyAndProcess(files, props);
    done();
  });
};
```

Everything works fine: files and folder are correctly generated or renamed from the `root` folder of the custom template based on `rename.json` info.

The question is: how can i also dynamically rename folders and not only files?

i.e.

```
{
    "libs/name.js": "libs/{%= name %}.js" //this works fine
    "src/name": "src/{%= name %}" //this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: sry for the question, but what exactly do you need the `type: 'skin'` for?

Answer (score 3):

The `init.filesToCopy` method only looks at `renames.json` for specific file (not directory) matches when it first builds the `files` object. Your best bet is to programmatically modify the `files` object between `init.filesToCopy` and `init.copyAndProcess`.

Comment: do you mean that i have to manually replace the folder name by looping the files object between init.filesToCopy and init.copyAndProcess?

Comment: Try `console.log(files)` to see what it contains. Then, modify it programmatically.

Comment: i tried to modify it in this way, but seems taht the copyAndProcess still get the original object http://d.pr/n/UIGr thanks a lot Ben for the support

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by modifying the result of the init.filesToCopy object.  However you need to modify the key rather than the value of each pair.

For example, I have a folder called lib/ that I wish to copy the contents into app/

```
var files = init.filesToCopy(props),
    libFolder = 'app';

// Repath the files correctly
for (var file in files) {
    if (file.indexOf('lib/') > -1) {
        var path = files[file],
            newFile = file.replace('lib/', libFolder + '/');
        files[newFile] = path;
        delete files[file];
    }
}

init.copyAndProcess(files, props);
```

It's also worth noting that rename.json works on the lib/ value *not* the new folder.

One thing that I've done is to use the props.main value to extract the libFolder value (e.g. libFolder = props.main.split('/')[0])

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this and get around the limitation of not being able to rename folders, is to 1) setup a grunt-contrib-copy task to copy the folders and files and apply whatever names you require to the new folders/files, and then 2) have a grunt-contrib-clean task clean out the old files/folders resulting in the same net effect as renaming the folders.

Comment: after learning more about grunt-init, this is not useful in the least. live and learn, I thought it made sense at the time...